# Imagej getting a summary to be displayed and extracting its values

Tags: java, imagej, threshold

I am trying to build a simple java app, which would count particles and then display their number. I am using imagej (ij.jar) library, everything works perfect until the little box with result is supposed to be shown. COuld anyone pease explain to me how can I display that. And the second thing, how do I extract that value to an int.

my current code:
button action, which leads to:

```
ImagePlus imp = IJ.openImage("C:\\Users\\bibaleze69\\Desktop\\imageprocessing\\chromosomes2.jpg");
imp1.show();
IJ.run(imp, "Color Threshold...", "");       
IJ.run(imp, "Analyze Particles...", "show=[Overlay Outlines] display summarize");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I extract that value to an int.

I believe you want to use the [Results Table](http://imagej.net/developer/api/ij/measure/ResultsTable.html) API. `ResultsTable.getResultsTable` will get the active results after your `Analyze Particles` command, and you can then interrogate it with the `getValue` methods.

> COuld anyone pease explain to me how can I display that

I think your `Analyze Particles` isn't running because running `Color Threshold...` doesn't actually apply the threshold to create a mask or 8-bit image, it just opens the thresholding interface. I actually had a lot of trouble trying to get the `Color Threshold` to apply. I think you have a couple options though:

- If you run `Color Threshold` in Fiji, and open the `Macro Recorder`, you can press the "Macro" button in the `Color Threshold` dialog to dump a ton of IJ1 Macro code to the recorder. This code will actually apply the selected threshold to your image and create an image that can then be input to `Analyze Particles`. But you would have to replicate this process on the Java side and I don't know how flexible it will be.
- Alternately, you can adapt the following IJ1 Macro code to just threshold the image as 8-bit.

  `run("8-bit");
  setAutoThreshold("Default");
  //run("Threshold...");
  setOption("BlackBackground", false);
  run("Convert to Mask");`

  If you can get the desired threshold from just operating on an 8-bit version of your image then this is a much simpler option to get your data to `Analyze Particles`.

If these options don't fully work for you, I would also recommend writing to the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.net/Mailing_Lists), which is read by the `Threshold Colour` author, among many others.

Comment: Thanks, i actually figured it out after a day but your additional info helps a lot too.